# Using [UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:] with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout that has UIDynamics

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uikit-dynamics

Okay so basic overview. I have a `UICollectionView` that I needs to support adding and removing item through the `performBatchUpdates:` method. If I use a standard `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, it works fine.

However, when I try to use a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that is powered by a `UIDynamicAnimator`, then I get a crash as soon as I call `performBatchChanges`.

On my custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` class, the `prepareForCollectionViewUpdates:` method never gets called. The custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that I am using is based off of [this sample](https://github.com/objcio/issue-5-springy-collection-view).

The console output after the crash is...

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UICollectionViewData.m:581
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000028096> {length = 2, path = 2 - 5}'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find a fix for this? The answer below covers when cell is not visible, but this is happening to me when the cell is visible, and it's random crash happening in prod that I cannot reproduce myself. I don't even use a UIDynamicAnimator

Comment: The answer blow worked for me, it was the correct fix for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [self.dynamicAnimator layoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!layoutAttributes) {
        layoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return layoutAttributes;
}
```

when you execute `performBatchUpdates`, `[self.dynamicAnimator layoutAttributesForCellAtIndexPath:`  returns `nil` if cell which will be created by update is not visible.
So just returns `super`(perhaps `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`)'
s `layoutAttributes` for now.
And when the cell about to be displayed, `UIDynamicAnimator` will do the job for you.

Comment: How should I use your code, I got a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46599911/6536841).